# bootstrap content under/behind navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Why is it that the same code have a nice top margin on bootstrap example, but if i put it in a jsfiddle the content is under the navigation

http://jsfiddle.net/a60x81gw/

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/

im using theese librarys

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

code

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">

  <div class="starter-template">
    <h1>Bootstrap starter template</h1>
    <p class="lead">Use this document as a way to quickly start any new project.<br> All you get is this text and a mostly barebones HTML document.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That template includes a `padding` on the `body` to avoid the overlap with the fixed navbar.

```
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
```

As mentioned on the documentation:

> **Body padding required** The fixed navbar will overlay your other content, unless you add padding to the top of the body. Try out your own values or use our snippet below. Tip: By default, the navbar is 50px high.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

Comment: thanks for your answare, o mark this right because it has most votes

Answer (score 0):

Add into the css box on fiddle

```
.starter-template {
padding: 40px 15px;
text-align: center;
}
```

The bootstrap template is using its own custom css file while your fiddle doesnt have this file.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use the fixed to yop navigation. As documented in the bootstrap documentation, you have to give a `padding` to the `body` of your page. e.g.

```
body{
padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Quote from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-top

"Fixed to top

Add .navbar-fixed-top and remember to account for the hidden area underneath it by adding at least 40px padding to the `<body>`. Be sure to add this after the core Bootstrap CSS and before the optional responsive CSS."

Comment: Note the question is tagged with bootstrap3 so you may want to include the reference quote to that version